# attempt to index nil with 'CameraMaxZoomDistance' I tried searching for solutions, but didn't find even one

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make the players max zoom distance more depending on the powr (strength) they have, because the more strength the bigger the character is.

But I'm getting the above error:

> attempt to index nil with 'CameraMaxZoomDistance'

Here is my code:

```
            hum:WaitForChild("BodyDepthScale").Value = .5 + (powr.Value / 250)
            hum:WaitForChild("BodyHeightScale").Value = .5 + (powr.Value / 250)
            hum:WaitForChild("BodyWidthScale").Value = .5 + (powr.Value / 250)
            hum:WaitForChild("HeadScale").Value = .5 + (powr.Value / 250)
            if powr.Value > 1000 then
                game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.CameraMaxZoomDistance = powr.Value / 50
            end
            if powr.Value > 200 then
                print('higher')
                hum.MaxHealth = powr.Value / 2
            end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying that `game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer` is nil. According to the docs for [LocalPlayer](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer) :

> This property is only defined for LocalScripts (and ModuleScripts required by them), as they run on the client. For the server (on which Script objects run their code), this property is nil.

You're trying to access the [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) object for a specific character model, and there are a few different ways to get it. You already have access to the humanoid object, which is in the character model itself, so I would recommend using the [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter) function to locate the Player object.

```
if powr.Value > 1000 then
    -- get the character model
    local character = hum.Parent

    -- lookup the player based on the character
    local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")
    local player = PlayerService:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)
    if not player then
        warn("Could not locate player from character : ", character.Name)
        return
    end

    -- adjust the player's camera zoom distance
    player.CameraMaxZoomDistance = powr.Value / 50
end
```